# Why does pandas hide columns during display?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
print  data.head()
data ['Check value'] = data['Low'] > 10
print  data.head()
```

The above code produce following output:

```
                Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close   Volume
Date                                                      
2018-03-01  10.93  10.95  10.75  10.80  10.752876  2784400
2018-03-02  10.74  10.78  10.62  10.77  10.723008  1472800
2018-03-05  10.75  11.05  10.75  11.02  10.971917  1452300
2018-03-06  11.09  11.11  10.95  10.97  10.922135  1121300
2018-03-07  10.94  11.06  10.80  10.88  10.832527  2179900
             Open   High    Low     ...       Adj Close   Volume  Check value
Date                                ...                                      
2018-03-01  10.93  10.95  10.75     ...       10.752876  2784400         True
2018-03-02  10.74  10.78  10.62     ...       10.723008  1472800         True
2018-03-05  10.75  11.05  10.75     ...       10.971917  1452300         True
2018-03-06  11.09  11.11  10.95     ...       10.922135  1121300         True
2018-03-07  10.94  11.06  10.80     ...       10.832527  2179900    

 True
```

**Why there are 3 dots in the middle?  This dot should  not be there.**